# Questions about internal containers in the STL stack

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

```
string s; cin >> s;
stack<char, string> Left(s);
```

I understood that the second parameter is related to the container and that the default container on the stack is a deque.

```
string s; cin >> s;
stack<char> Left(s);
```

But I don't understand why I can't just put the s right in if I clear the string in the second one - after all, aren't they both char arrays in contiguous memory space?

- The code above works and the code below does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/deduction_guides) works if you don't supply *any* template parameters. The deduction guide you want to use in this case is:

```cpp
template< class Container >
stack( Container )
  -> stack<typename Container::value_type, Container>;
```

Which means that you simply need to remove `char`:

```cpp
stack Left(s);
```

`Left` will now be a `std::stack<char, std::string>`, which can be verified by

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
//...
static_assert(std::is_same_v<stack<char, string>, decltype(Left)>);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that the 2nd parameter is related to specifying the default container? I still don't see how using a string container is different from using the default container, deque.

Comment: @noobdam Yes, the 2nd parameter is specifying the container type. A `deque` will probably require a lot more space than a `string` and strings store their data as a continuous array. For a stack, I'd expect the string version to be faster for `char`s - but I haven't measured so it's just a guess.